# Connecting to Web services via Power BI Service

Tags: office365, powerbi

Using Power BI Desktop I've successfully connected to a web data source via an API query (Teamwork.com) that I'd lke to analyze. Specifically, however, I need this data to refresh daily and to be viewable by my work group (O 365 environment). The content is not available in one of the service packs listed on the Power BI Library which is discouraging.

Is there any way to do what I'm trying to do within the confines of Power BI? If so, what combination of services/gateways, etc will I need in order to see daily refreshed data directly from Teamwork.com without needing a manual refresh + publish?

Answer (score 0):

Generally online data sources work only with the Personal Gateway. I've been using it successfully for the reports build in Power BI Desktop and published to Web.

Answer (score 0):

Just an update for those who happen to land and search on this page. Power BI Gateway (personal) can allow a web sourced data refresh to populate to PBI.com provided your machine is on and connected to the web (PBI Desktop doesn't need to be open but the Gateway app in your system tray does). Once you've published your data set/report, you can schedule a refresh. HOWEVER if you have any scripts running alongside your data set they WILL NOT populate to PBI.com. This is what was hindering me here as I had a script to paginate my API call to the web.